# Avoiding certain files in the Chrome timeline tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I have a web app which uses AngularJS as FE.

I would like to check the performance of the controllers and services I have created. I use the chrome timeline tool but there is a lot of noise there, especially from known files like jquery.js, angular.js, etc..

Is there a way to ignore these files or maybe filter it so I can see my files and modules better?

**Edited:**

I'm talking about the performance tab, not the network tab where we have a filter